# Show and hide input fields using 4 radio buttons using HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, hide, show

I am a complete beginner with Javascript.

I have 4 radio buttons:

1. House
2. Flat / Apartment
3. Bungalow
4. Commercial

And 2 input fields:

1. Rooms:
2. Bedrooms:

on click of House, Flat, Bungalow, I want to hide Rooms and show the input field Bedrooms on click of commercial I want to hide Bedrooms and show Rooms.

Please see my code below:

**HTML CODE:**

```
<table id="CurrentProperty">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <label>Type of Property:</label>
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" id="showBedrooms" value="bedrooms" name="fromType" checked="checked" />House
            <input type="radio" id="showBedrooms" value="bedrooms" name="fromType" />Flat / Appartment
            <input type="radio" id="showBedrooms" value="bedrooms" name="fromType" />Bungalow
            <input type="radio" id="showRooms" value="rooms" name="fromType" />Commercial</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="showCta">
        <td colspan="3">
            <label>Rooms:</label>
            <input name="fromRooms" lable="From Rooms" type="text" class="body" ID="fromRooms" size="10" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="showTr">
        <td colspan="3">
            <label>Bedrooms:</label>
            <input name="fromBedrooms" lable="From Bedrooms" type="text" class="body" ID="fromBedrooms" size="10" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#showBedrooms').on('click', function () {
        $('.showCta').hide();
    });
});

$(window).load(function () {
    $('#showRooms').on('click', function () {
        $('.showCta').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

JS should be something like

```
function update (el) {
    var $rooms = $('tr.showCta');
    var $bedrooms = $('tr.showTr');

    if (el.checked && el.value === 'bedrooms') {
        $rooms.hide();
        $bedrooms.show();
    } else {
        $rooms.show();
        $bedrooms.hide();
    }
}

$(function () {
    //get initial state.
    update($('input:checked')[0]);
    $('input[name="fromType"]').change(function () {
        update(this);
    });
});
```

jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bj4Lx7ms/

Answer (score 0):

in your case, user [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) from jquery. Bind an event handler to the "change" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element (your radiobuttons). With `$(this).val()` you can get the value from the value attribute, to check is the value bedrooms. Then call the methode show or hide like in this example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:radio[name="fromType"]').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 'bedrooms'){
           $('.showCta').hide();
           $('.showTr').show();
        }else if ($(this).val() == 'rooms'){
            $('.showCta').show();
            $('.showTr').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

And hide the `showCta tr` as default with:

```
<tr class="showCta" style="display:none">
```

[Here my JsFiddle-example](http://jsfiddle.net/p2juduk9/)

Answer (score 0):

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$( document ).ready(function () {
    $('#showBedrooms').on('click', function () {
        $('.showCta').hide();
    });
    $('#showRooms').on('click', function () {
        $('.showCta').show();
    });
});
```

After the document loaded and set the onclick handlder

And I think you should set

```
<tr class="showCta">
```

to

```
<tr class="showCta" style="display:none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).load(function () { /* You don't need to call twice this function, just wrap all your function in it */
    function hideRooms() {
      $("#rooms").hide(0);
      $("#bedrooms").fadeIn(250);
    }
  
    function hideBedrooms() {
      $("#bedrooms").hide(0);
      $("#rooms").fadeIn(250);
    }
  
    $("#label").text("House selected");
  
    hideRooms(); /* Hidding at start of website */
  
    $("#showBedrooms_house").change(function() {      
      $("#label").text("House selected");
      if (this.checked) {
        hideRooms();        
      }
    });
  
    $("#showBedrooms_flatAppart").change(function() {
      $("#label").text("Flat / Appartment selecrted");
      if (this.checked) {
        hideRooms();
      }
    });
  
    $("#showBedrooms_bungalow").change(function() {
      $("#label").text("Bungalow selected");
      if (this.checked) {
        hideRooms();
      }
    });
  
    $("#showRooms_commercial").change(function() {
      $("#label").text("Commercial selected");
      if (this.checked) {
        hideBedrooms();
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="CurrentProperty">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <label>Type of Property:</label>
            <br/>
            <input type="radio" id="showBedrooms_house" value="bedrooms" name="fromType" checked="checked" />House
            <input type="radio" id="showBedrooms_flatAppart" value="bedrooms" name="fromType" />Flat / Appartment
            <input type="radio" id="showBedrooms_bungalow" value="bedrooms" name="fromType" />Bungalow
            <input type="radio" id="showRooms_commercial" value="rooms" name="fromType" />Commercial</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="showCta" id = "rooms">
        <td colspan="3">
            <label>Rooms:</label>
            <input name="fromRooms" lable="From Rooms" type="text" class="body" ID="fromRooms" size="10" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="showTr" id = "bedrooms">
        <td colspan="3">
            <label>Bedrooms:</label>
            <input name="fromBedrooms" lable="From Bedrooms" type="text" class="body" ID="fromBedrooms" size="10" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style ="color : blue">
          <label id ="label"></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Using this code how can I obtain which has been selected such as House, Flat, Commercial at present I am getting bedrooms as the output.

Comment: @Lisa code updated, it now display the option selected below the textBox.